# C# WinForms flickering on any type of fast screen update

Tags: c#, winforms, drawing, flicker

I want to create a drawing library, so that i could visualize some code (something like processing for java). Updating the drawn causes flickering and I cannot find a way to fix it.
I am drawing with the Drawing class and WinForms.
If there is another/a better way to realize this with using something else (except for Unity), I am willing to try that.

I tried it with double buffering, which did nothing. Invalidate and Refresh made it much worse.

EDIT: It got fixed (see comments). I used a timer found [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20110910100053/http://www.indigo79.net/archives/27)

The following is my Form class.

```
Timer timer;
int i = 0;

Screen screen;
Rectangle canvas;

public Form1() {
    InitializeComponent();
    this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
    this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
    this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
    DoubleBuffered = true;

    screen = Screen.FromControl(this);
    canvas = screen.WorkingArea;

    timer = new Timer();
    timer.Interval = 10;

    timer.Tick += new EventHandler(draw);

    timer.Enabled = true;
}

public void draw(object source, EventArgs e) {
    Graphics g = CreateGraphics();

    g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Black), canvas);
    g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.White), i, 0, 100, 100);
    i++;
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't be calling CreateGraphics, do your drawing in the OnPaint method and just Invalidate() in the timer.

Comment: ...and, If you refer to the documentation for the Timer, you will find that it is not capable of 10ms resolution.  AND nearly all graphics objects you create (such as a brush) must be disposed or your app will leak

Comment: ...the Paint() event provides a Graphics for you to draw with via `e.Graphics`.

Comment: It worked using the OnPaint method and Invalidate in the timer. @NatPongjardenlarp I now found a timer thats capable of going high resolutions

Answer (score 2):

Do not create the Graphics, use the one passed to the OnPaint.

On timer, just calculate coordinates and call Invalidate.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Flickering
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Timer timer;
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100);
        Size speed = new Size(3, 1);
        Size step = new Size(3, 1);

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint | ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer | ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint | ControlStyles.Opaque, true);

            timer = new Timer();
            timer.Interval = 20;
            timer.Tick += new EventHandler(Tick);
            timer.Enabled = true;
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            //e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.DarkCyan, ClientRectangle);
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, rect);
        }

        public void Tick(object source, EventArgs e)
        {
            var canvas = ClientRectangle;
            step.Width = rect.Right >= canvas.Width ? -speed.Width : rect.Left < canvas.Left ? speed.Width : step.Width;
            step.Height = rect.Bottom >= canvas.Height ? -speed.Height : rect.Top < canvas.Top ? speed.Height : step.Height;
            rect.Location += step;

            Invalidate();
        }
    }
}
```